# Mock lazyInject objects in typescript(Inversify) using Jest JS

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, inversifyjs

I used @lazyInject for inject the dependencies to some service classes.

```
let container = new Container();
container.bind<StudentServiceImpl>(TYPES.StudentService).to(StudentServiceImpl);
let {lazyInject} = getDecorators(container);

@Service(TYPES.CoreService)
export class CoreServiceImpl implements CoreService {


    @lazyInject(TYPES.StudentService)
    private studentService: StudentServiceImpl;
}
```

How can I mock this lazyInject object using Jest JS.
Any help or workarounds are really appreciate.

Comment: Are you using [inversify-inject-decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-inject-decorators) package?